# πλήθει, dual use of πλῆθος in Philebus

Tags: greek, dual, ancient-greek

One word seems to me somehow very strange with its dual number. It is in a passage from Plato's Philebus:

> φωνὴ μὲν ἡμῖν ἐστί που μία διὰ τοῦ στόματος ἰοῦσα,  καὶ ἄπειρος αὖ
> **πλήθει**, πάντων τε καὶ ἑκάστου.

with a translation:

> Sound, which passes out through the mouth of each and all of us, is
> one, and yet again it is infinite in number.

The word πλήθει is, as far as I've checked, a dual word of πλῆθος, meaning "a great number".
I would think that the word shall be used as either singular or plural.
Is there a reason that this word is especially dual?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't dual; it's dative singular. The dative is a dative of respect and depends on the adjective ἄπειρος. Therefore, the phrase ἄπειρος...πλήθει means 'limitless in (with respect to) magnitude/extent/quantity.'

Comment: Importantly, this implies "a lot" -- not just an indefinite quantity.

Answer (score 6):

In the case you mention, πλήθει is actually the **dative singular** of πλῆθος. This is the standard declension for neuter 3rd declension nouns ending in vowel + sigma, as indicated on [this page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Ancient_Greek_third_declension) with the model of "τέλος."

It is a [dative of respect](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Smyth%20grammar%201516&lang=original) modifying ἄπειρος, as the translation accurately captures: "infinite **in number**."